# JQgrid date formatter Ymd

Tags: jqgrid

I have a problem with the jqgrid Date formatter.
in my DB table i have this dateformat "Ymd" like "20120219".
Here the whole code for this column:

```
$col = array();
$col["title"] = "Date";
$col["name"] = "date_dem";
$col["width"] = "40";
$col["editable"] = false;
$col["editoptions"] = array("size"=>20);
$col["formatter"] = "date"; // format as date
$col["formatoptions"] = array("srcformat"=>'Ymd',"newformat"=>'d/m/Y');
$cols[] = $col;
```

When i use this code i get for every record the same output: "01/01/1970".
Anybody knows this problem?

THX in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the information about the date are saved as `Ymd` without any separators you have to return from the server the information *with some separator* between year, month and day. The problem is that the current code of jqGrid first split the input date using `'\'`, `'/'`, `':'`, `'_'`, `';'`, `'.'` or `','` as separator (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L160) of code)

```
date = String(date).split(/[\\\/:_;.,\t\T\s-]/);
```

and then use the `srcformat` to decode it. So you can't use `formatter: "date"` to decode the date like `20121009`. I recommend you to convert `20121009` to `2012-10-09` *on the server side* and return from the server the date always in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format which is defalt format used by jqGrid. Alternatively you can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to display the date.

Comment: HI, Thank you for your answer. i think that i will convert this file in my table before.
THX